# Symfony2 - GeniusesOfSymfony/WebSocketBundle ssl error connection

Tags: symfony

I need to configure my project with ssl.

So, i have Mamp Pro, and i have created a new Generated SSL certificate.
My server is running via Https,

Right now, i cant connect to server via Javascripts client : 
After 10 sec, this is the javascripts error that ive got :

WebSocket connection to 'wss://127.0.0.1:4000/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT
(index):111 Disconnected for Connection could not be established. with code 3

and this is my configuration :

```
gos_web_socket:
    pushers:
        wamp:
            host: 127.0.0.1
            port: 4000
    server:
        port: 4000 #The port the socket server will listen on
        host: 127.0.0.1 #The host ip to bind to
    router:
        resources:
            - @AppBundle/Resources/config/pubsub/routing.yml
```

This is the javascripts code : 
var websocket = WS.connect("wss://127.0.0.1:4000");

```
websocket.on("socket/connect", function(session)
```

Any help please ?

Comment: Have you looked at the SSL Configuration page (https://github.com/GeniusesOfSymfony/WebSocketBundle/blob/master/Resources/docs/Ssl.md) ?

Comment: Ive found the solution :
Ive installed Stunned and ive configured stunned and my server :)
Thank you !